# Craft CMS Entry Form Update Existing Entries without Creating New Ones

Tags: entry-form

I'm building a Craft CMS entry form like the one at: https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/entry-form . It needs to update existing entries within the section when their titles match, but should never create a new entry. Right now it's creating new entries only. Code is:

```
{% macro errorList(errors) %}
  {% if errors %}
    {{ ul(errors, {class: 'errors'}) }}
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{% set entry = entry ?? create('craft\\elements\\Entry') %}

<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  {{ csrfInput() }}
  {{ actionInput('entries/save-entry') }}
  {{ redirectInput(entry.formRedirect.one.url) }}
  {{ hiddenInput('sectionId', '10') }}

  <div class="form-floating mb-3">
    <input type="email" id="title" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Email Address">
    <label for="title">Email Address</label>
  </div>

  <input style="display:none;" type="date" id="currentAccessStartDate" name="fields[currentAccessStartDate]" value="{{ now|date('Y-m-d') }}">
  <input style="display:none;" type="checkbox" id="sendEmailOnSave" name="fields[sendEmailOnSave]" value="1" checked="true">
  <button type="submit" class="btn-std">{{ entry.formButtonLabel }}</button>
</form>
```

I've also tried doing this with the Formie plugin from Verbb, which works well for updating existing entries, but doesn't seem to have any way to prevent it from creating new ones.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to update an already existing entry then you should add a hidden field for the entryId like below:

```
{{ hiddenInput('entryId', idOfTheExistingEntry) }}
```

Comment: Yep, that would work if i had the id of the existing entry, but I'm trying to match the entry based on the title field

Comment: @ClayKilby Where does your “entry” variable come from, in the example above?

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff that is the entry for the page this form appears on, which is not related to the entry it is saving to

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve is not possible to do using the stock [`entries/save-entry`](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/controllers/EntriesController.php#L311) controller action.

You'll likely need to [create a custom module](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/module-guide.html) with a custom [controller action](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/controllers.html) containing the logic required to

1. match the given title to an existing entry
2. set new field values from the form to the entry
3. re-save the entry
4. redirect